# Get details on a Network Location configuration

Tags: windows, windows-10, network-shares, kodi

I have Kodi running on a Raspberry Pi 3 (LibreELEC OS).
On my Windows 10 PC, in *This PC*, I can access Kodi's library under *Network Locations*:
[image: This PC - Windows Explorer]
But the thing is, I don't know the protocol nor the configuration used by Windows to access Kodi's library.
In its Properties, it doesn't indicate anything useful:
[image: Kodi Network Location]

This Network Location was added automatically through `Settings -> Devices -> Bluetooth Devices and others -> Add a device -> Anything else` (translated from my locale, hopefully it won't be too far-off from the actual path in English).

I suspect this access uses DLNA/UPnP, but haven't been able to confirm it.
How can I find relevant configuration information concerning this *Network Location*?

Comment: Kodi uses UPnP.

Comment: @MichaelBay Yes, I had UPnP turned on on Kodi, but I didn't find any information on the ports used, neither in Kodi nor in the documentation. Which was annoying because for some reason, Kodi's UPnP share didn't show up on my Android device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I headed to Windows' Device Manager and found the information I was looking for. It's located under `Software devices`:
[image: Kodi UPnP under Device Manager]
It was indeed DLNA/UPnP, as shown by the XML description file given as a location:

```
<root xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0" xmlns:dlna="urn:schemas-dlna-org:device-1-0" configId="15297301">
    <specVersion>
        <major>1</major>
        <minor>1</minor>
    </specVersion>
    <device>
        <deviceType>urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:MediaServer:1</deviceType>
        <friendlyName>Kodi (PlanteurJMTLG)</friendlyName>
        <manufacturer>Microsoft Corporation</manufacturer>
        <manufacturerURL>http://kodi.tv/</manufacturerURL>
        <modelDescription>Kodi - Media Server</modelDescription>
        <modelName>Kodi</modelName>
        <modelNumber>17.3 Git:147cec4</modelNumber>
        <modelURL>http://kodi.tv/</modelURL>
        <UDN>uuid:1afd630d-f8cc-e266-b85b-ae31baf3b99c</UDN>
        <presentationURL>http://192.168.1.51:8080/</presentationURL>
        <dlna:X_DLNADOC xmlns:dlna="urn:schemas-dlna-org:device-1-0">DMS-1.50</dlna:X_DLNADOC>
        <...>
    </device>
</root>
```

I used this location to configure the share on other devices. Hope this helps!